# Error while using client certificate in callouts

Tags: api, callout, namedcredentials, api-client-certificate

I am integrating with an external API which expects client certificate in the request. They had provided `.p12` file. I have converted it into `.jks` and imported in Salesforce.

I have tried to use it two ways and both failed.

1. `req.setClientCertificateName('certname')`
2. named credentials with this certificate

The error that is displayed on dev console when I execute the code is

```
System.CalloutException: PKIX path building failed: 

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Has anybody faced such issue or have any idea of potential reason for this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Your cert chain is not trusted by the other party - it's not clear from the exception whether this has to do with the your client cert or Salesforce having an issue with their cert.

Comment: @identigral you are right. I checked the certificate chain and found that the CA for this certificate is not listed in the trusted CAs list published by Salesforce. Maybe that is the issue.